# Instance Method not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am stumped, im not very good with Objective-C yet, and I have been following tutorials until now.

I have decided to add all the functions I use in multipul views in one "CommonClass" I have called GeneralHelper.

When trying to call my function im getting the following error:

> Instance method'-convertPoint:' not found(return type defaults to
>   'id')

Below is my code:

My GeneralHelper.h lookslike this:
        #import

```
    @interface GeneralHelper : NSObject

    @end

    GeneralHelper* gHelper;
```

My GeneralHelper.m looks like this:

```
    #import "GeneralHelper.h"
    #import "WhackGame.h"
    #import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
    #import "Settings.h"

    @implementation GeneralHelper
    -(CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point {
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            return ccp(32 + point.x*2, 64 + point.y*2);
        } else {
            return point;
        }
    }

    @end
```

Inside my Initialize method I have:

```
    gHelper = [[GeneralHelper alloc] init]; //First, we create an instance of GeneralHelper
```

and im trying to call it like:

```
    mole1.position = [gHelper convertPoint:ccp(85, 85)];
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't declare the method `convertPoint:` in your `@interface` like this:

```
@interface GeneralHelper : NSObject
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point;
@end
```

Also, if you're trying to have one shared instance of GeneralHelper, that's not the way to do it. Instead you should have a class method that returns an instance.

```
@interface GeneralHelper : NSObject
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point;
+ (GeneralHelper *)sharedHelper;
@end
```

Then in your implementation:

```
+ (GeneralHelper *)sharedHelper
{
    static GeneralHelper *sharedHelper = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedHelper = [[GeneralHelper alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedHelper;
}
```

And then wherever you need it:

```
CGPoint convertedPoint = [[GeneralHelper sharedHelper] convertPoint:point];
```

Alternatively you could simply use class methods:

```
@interface GeneralHelper : NSObject
+ (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point;
@end
```

The implementation is the same as before, but with a + instead of a - sign. In this case you don't need the `sharedHelper` method and can simply call it like this:

```
CGPoint convertedPoint = [GeneralHelper convertPoint:point];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your `convertPoint:` method in your class's interface.

```
@interface GeneralHelper : NSObject
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point;
@end
```

A header acts as "here is all the information you need to use this class," and one important piece of information is "here are the messages that you can send to this class, and what arguments they take."

Your specific warning is caused by the compiler being unable to figure out the return type of the method without seeing it in the interface.